# Theme Customizer - Allowing users to change background image of multiple divs

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to have a feature where users can change the background image of certain divs via the theme customizer. I've tried many different ways but can't seem to get it to work.

As of right now I have it to where I'm able to change the background of one div but not able to get more than that one.

Function.php file

```
function meraki_custom_background_cb() {
ob_start();
_custom_background_cb(); // Default handler
$style = ob_get_clean();
 $style = str_replace( 'body.custom-background', '#featured-home-image', $style );

echo $style;
}

add_theme_support( 'custom-background',
array(
    'wp-head-callback' => 'meraki_custom_background_cb',
    'default-color'    => '000000',
    'default-image'    => '%1$s/images/background.jpg',
)

);
```

header.php file

```
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-color: #bdd96e; }
</style>
```

I'm pretty sure what this is doing is just replacing the string 'body.custom-background' with the ID #featured-homeimage', which works great, but only for one div.

Is there a way to make this possible for multiple divs? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I found a workaround for now. The divs  I'm wanting the user to have the ability to change the background image to are also pulling in content from posts tagged with a certain key word. So what I did was also pull in the featured image from that post and styled it to lay in the background of the div. Example: `<!-- post thumbnail -->
<div class="post-thumbnail" style="z-index: -10; position:absolute; overflow: hidden; margin-top: -4.5%;">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('banner-image'); ?>
</div>
<!-- /post thumbnail -->` This made it work perfectly for now till I find a better work around.